# Showing that every undirected simple graph $G$ contains a path of length $\delta(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

This is proposition 1.3.1 of Diestel's graph theory, 5th edition. The claim is that every simple undirected graph $G$ contains a path of length $\delta(G)$, when $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of the graph $G$. I understand that you can show that the longest path in $G$ has to have a length of at least $\delta(G)$ since every neighbor of the terminal vertex has to lie on the assumed maximal path. But I don't know how to show the existence of a path with length $\delta(G)$, as stipulated by the claim.

One observation is that every neighbor of the vertex with degree $\delta(G)$ has at least $\delta(G) - 1$ neighbors other than the chosen minimal vertex. Perhaps we have to do some Pigeonhole principle type of argument by considering neighbors of the neighbors of the selected minimal vertex?

Comment: If you've shown the longest path has to have length at least $\delta(G)$, aren't you done? The graph has to have a longest path.

Comment: @MishaLavrov But doesn't the wording dictate that we have to show that there exists a path with length exactly $\delta(G)$? In this case, I don't see how knowledge of the lower bound on the longest path helps us.

Comment: You can take an initial segment of the path to get a shorter path if you want.

Comment: @SamOT I think it does. The accepted solution is essentially my idea, but I just wasn't fully convinced by it. The important thing (not included in the said accepted solution), is that the only way the process of taking and deleting vertices can fail before $\delta(G)$ steps is if some vertex has a degree less than $\delta(G)$. But this violates the definition of $\delta(G)$. Thus we can take and delete exactly $\delta(G)$ vertices from $G$, such that they form a path.